# Querying remote MySql database with bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm trying to query remote database with the following script.

```
some_db="somedb"
isAnythingToProcess=$(mysql -uroot -proot -D$some_db -e "$checkSearch");
```

This works for me locally however whenever i try to run bash script to remote AWS server I get error

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'somedb'

Any hints?

P.S. The database exists for sure. I can connect to it via MySQL client.

Comment: How are you connecting to remote server?

Comment: The code is part of my larger bash script.  As a client application I use Sequel Pro

Comment: The fact that the client can connect has _nothing_ to do with the question if that database exists. One MySQL server holds many databases. If that server tells you the database does not exist, then most likely it does not or you do not have the permission to use it.

Comment: You have to add -h and specify the host name it should be $(mysql -uroot -proot -D$some_db -h<host> -e "$checkSearch");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the parameter for remote host `-h`

```
some_db="somedb"
isAnythingToProcess=$(mysql -uroot -proot -h REMOTE_IP -D$some_db -e "$checkSearch");
```

Comment: Obvious mistake. Thank you. Feel stupid posting question about it.

Comment: Mistake happens, no problem :)